# Are single queries that update multiple rows in MySQL Atomic?

Tags: mysql, atomic

I have a single query in a MySQL InnoDb table being executed in SpringJPA that updates multiple rows. I want to make sure that the query completes and that the rows it will update cannot be updated by any other process. This is in a multi-cpu environment so I have to do the locking at the database level.

I first select the rows with a query like this:

```
select * from tablea where status = 1;
```

Let's say this returns 3 rows - primary ids 1,2,3

I want to prevent concurrent update and I do this update:

```
update tablea set status=2 where status=1 and primaryIds in (1,2,3);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to check that all the rows I'm trying to update still have the original value in status and have not been updated underneath me. I then get the count of rows updated and compare it to the number of primary ids (3) to know if my query has updated all rows. My question is this query atomic - will it either return 3 or 0. And if the number of rows is much greater will it yield allowing another thread, trying to do the same update to update some rows. I have tested this with one row and it works fine.

Comment: Being atomic is NOT the same as returning 3 or 0 as the number of affected rows for your query! Being atomic means that it will either run completely or doesn't change anything at all (e.g. if it encounters an error in row 2, it will undo changes to row 1). It does not mean that the data cannot change between the select and the update. If you actually want to make sure of this, please be more precise/reword it, especially your title, as you (maybe) do not actually want to know if a single query is atomic.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I think you understood my question. And that is, will it guarantee that all three rows are updated or none are updated. Is there a chance that 2 rows will be updated and one will not.

Comment: Yes there is (if someone updated the table between your select and the update). But my edit suggestion was to make sure that not only me, but everyone else will not overlook the 7 words "will it either return 3 or 0"  which makes this a completely different question (and especially does not match your title). Including future readers that have the question as in your title and find this question via a search engine and will see an answer that says "no" and think it answers the question in the title. And if someone has your actual problem, noone will find it by just those 7 words.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. Assuming you have auto-commit enabled (this is the default when you haven't started a transaction), InnoDB will automatically put a transaction around each query, which makes it atomic. It's effectively equivalent to:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update tablea set status=2 where status=1 and primaryIds in (1,2,3);
COMMIT;
```